# How strict transport security header should applied on www subdomain?

Tags: http, https, hsts

I want to add [strict transport security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) header to my website https response with `includeSubDomains` and `preload` options. Which would look like this:

> Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload

Also, my hosting providers have these redirect flows:

1. http -> https -> https://www.
2. https -> https://www.

That means users always end up at https://www. url.

I noticed that Amazon has a similar redirect flow. See images below.

And it returns hsts header only on www response. Also, I checked hsts preload registration [website](https://hstspreload.org/) list and it has registered [www.amazon.de](http://www.amazon.de) but not amazon.de.

So, I have the following questions:

1. If I add hsts with `includeSubDomains` on `www.example.com` that means other subdomains like `admin.example.com` won't be protected? Maybe there are some exceptions for www subdomain?
2. If I register `www.example.com` to hsts preload registration list, this means that `example.com` still won't be protected against first request?
3. What is the point of having hsts on www website when you have anyways http->https redirects and base domain(example.com) is not preloaded(amazon example)?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

> If I add hsts with `includeSubDomains` on `www.example.com` that means other subdomains like `admin.example.com` won't be protected?

Yes. [From RFC 6797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-6.1.2):

> 6.1.2.  The includeSubDomains Directive
>
> The OPTIONAL "includeSubDomains" directive is a valueless directive
> which, if present (i.e., it is "asserted"), signals the UA that the
> HSTS Policy applies to this HSTS Host as well as any subdomains of
> the host's domain name.

There are no special rules for the www subdomain.

---

> If I register [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to hsts preload registration list, this means that example.com still won't be protected against first request?

You can only register `example.com`, not `www.example.com` - [see for yourself](https://hstspreload.org/?domain=www.example.com). Generally, you can only register an [etld+1](https://jfhr.me/what-is-an-etld-+-1/).

You might be able to get an exception if you're a very large company. See the [Chromium preload file](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:net/http/transport_security_state_static.json) - there are special rules for Google, Amazon and a few others, but everyone else can only preload whole domains.

---

> What is the point of having hsts on www website when you have anyways http->https redirects and base domain(example.com) is not preloaded(amazon example)?

This means that a browsers first request to `amazon.com` is insecure, but after the first request the browser will remember the HSTS header and subsequent requests to `amazon.com` will be secure. If they had the redirect but no HSTS, every request to `amazon.com` would be insecure.

Comment: 2. So, for a small website, it is impossible to protect the FIRST request to http://example.com, right?

Comment: You can still add example.com to the preload list and then the first request will be protected. You just can't add only www.example.com or some other subdomain.

Comment: Thanks, any reasons why they don't allow to add subdomains to preload list? Because www is called quite often and its first request remains unprotected.

Comment: If you add example.com to the preload list, then the first request to www.example.com will also be protected. The preload applies to the etld+1 and all subdomains. They don't allow you to add individual subdomains because the list would become too big.

Comment: _The preload applies to the etld+1 and all subdomains._ - can you please provide a source for this? Didn't see it anywhere and this part confused me the most.